# Change the oder/location of yes/no or OK/Cancel on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, lxde

I'm a Windows user and the backwards nature of Linux and some Open Source apps/programs prompts drives me nuts because I am used to things a different way.

How can I change the location of the yes/no and OK/Cancel propmts?  They need to be swapped.

I found this question, but it had no answer and Raspbian uses LXDE I think, not GNOME nor KDE.

[How to give the same order for "OK" and "Cancel" buttons in KDE and GNOME applications?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149818/how-to-give-the-same-order-for-ok-and-cancel-buttons-in-kde-and-gnome-applic)

Comment: Prompts in what? Terminal output?

Comment: Write to Microsoft and get them to swap the positions of their Yes/No and OK/Cancel prompts.  I believe that the Windows ones are backwards.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is the same as for Windows: edit the source and recompile.